# Timeout in JBI on Apache Camel

Tags: timeout, apache-camel, jbi

I'm developing a JBI component which calls another JBI component through Camel route. The second component performs some kind of long operation that sometimes may hang up. I would like to configure my Camel route so that it would be restricted with timeout (let's say 5 seconds). It should somehow behave as asynchronous call... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't think that's possible due the asynchronous nature of JBI.